# "Object Not Found"-Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am doing a simple laravel project.But I am getting this error.

Here is my view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <title>Calculator</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: #d8d7d7">
        <div class="container text-center">
        <br><br><br>
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="/c">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <select class="form-control" name="operator" required>
                        <option value="" selected=""> --Select Operator-- </option>
                        <option value="plus"> + </option>
                        <option value="minus"> - </option>
                        <option value="multiply"> * </option>
                        <option value="divide"> / </option>
                    </select>
                </div> 
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input class="form-control" type="number" name="first" placeholder="Enter First Number" required>
                </div> 
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input class="form-control" type="number" name="second" placeholder="Enter Second Number" required>
                </div>
                <div class="co;-md-3">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>

            </div>   
        </form>
        </div>

       <script source="js/jquery.js"></script>
       <script source="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CalculatorController extends Controller
{
    public function cf(Request $request)
    {
        echo "All OK";
    }
}
```

And my Route :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::post('/c', 'CalculatorController@cf');
```

I am getting this error :
"Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster."

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you did not configure your webserver/site correctly, most likely not correctly setup for "pretty urls"

Answer (score -1):

You are calling your route with a post method

try to edit the line like

```
Route::get('/c', 'CalculatorController@cf');
```

Or make sure your are making an post HTTP request method.

Good luck

Comment: My HTTP request method is post method. I tried with a get method too, but it showed the same error. Thinking of starting from the beginning again.